# output format like real Array ex) [1,2,5,3,5]

Tags: java

i have n number and i wanna to show them in console like this format 
example :

```
my numbers : 1 2 4 5 6
console output : [1,2,4,5,6]
```

i try this for my array but  output of this code is `[1,2,4,5,6,]`
that has an extra (,) at the end of numbers in console

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter length of array = ");
int length = scanner.nextInt();
int[] numbers = new int[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
for (int i : numbers) {
    System.out.printf("%d, ",i);
}
```

Comment: So don't print a comma after the last number.

Comment: [`Arrays.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29)?

Comment: If you want to achieve your functionality using enhanced for loop only then try [**this**](https://onlinegdb.com/SyLxi97jI)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a traditional for loop, you can print all but the last

```
for (int i = 0; i < length -1; i++) {

    System.out.printf("%d, ",numbers[i]);
}

// and then print the last
System.out.printf("%d",numbers[length -1]);
```

or of course use Arrays.toString

```
int [] arr  = {1,2,3,6,9};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: @MehdiNZ If this did answer your question, consider accepting it by clicking the check mark next to it.